# How do social networking websites handle notifications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, notifications, social-networking

I am implementing a small social networking website, and I am trying to implement notifications.

Notifications have the following requirements

- All users will receive notifications whenever users they follow do certain events (change profile picture, like a post, create a post, leave a comment, etc...
- Notifications have a status read or unread (like facebook and stackoverflow). When a set of notifications for a user is unread, then like facebook, the user will continue to see a read notification icon on their navbar

Here is how I am thinking of implementing it with MySQL:

**Notification table**: `type_of_event`, `event_id`, `message`
**Notification_read table**: `user_id`, `notification_id`, `read`

- Whenever a user does a event that triggers notifications to be sent
  to all of their followers, that notification is stored inside the `Notification` table
- The `Notification_read` table will be filled out for the newly created notification, with the new notification's id & the id of each user that should receive the notification (the notification creator's followers)
- Whenever a user receive notifications and reads them, the notification will be marked as `read`

This solution seems really inefficient to me because everytime a notification happens, the notification would be written in the `notification_read` table many times (depending on how many followers the user has)

Can someone tell me if there is a better solution to this problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With these kind of problems the tradeoff is often read vs write.

In this case, write can be expressed in time it takes to write the notification(s) to the database and the cost of storage.

For reading, it is about how fast you can get the notifications for a specific user.

In the example by @kecebongsoft, you are very efficient in write (because relative few fields) but read takes a lot of time. Searching in a text-field of a database is often slow. For a user you have to check all notifications and their check field if the user is listed and if so, what the status is.

By storing a separate notification for each user you increase your storage, but you gain a lot in the reading side. That is, because you can search an indexed table using the user ID and quickly find any notifications and their status.

Off course, there are very complicated hybrid methods. But generally, big websites don't like to tell those secrets :)

If you are starting with a site, I would not worry about the writing-cost. Populating a table with many notifications is not that expensive. In the end, they wil all be probably relative small. You could even think about pruning old notifications.

More important is the speed of reading. People that discover your site will not be impressed by your efficient storage adapter, but will notice the lighting speed when they receive their notifications.

My advice: for now focus on the read speed, and when you scale worry about storage efficiency.

Last note: if you are creating a lot of database entries when creating the notifications, look into solutions that do so dispatched from the main webserver thread. That way, the person creating the notification can continue quickly and you can do the expensive SQL stuff in the background. More speed!

Answer (score 2):

You can serialise your the recipients of an event and store it in the field. That way no matter how much the followers, the notification of one event will always be one.

```
Actor   ObjectType    ObjectID  Date        Recipients
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
UserA   Post          1         2014-03-02  [
                                            {'u': 1, 'r': False, 'dr': None},
                                            {'u': 2, 'r': True, 'dr': '2013-03-02'},
                                            {'u': 3, 'r': False, 'dr': None},
                                            {'u': 4, 'r': False, 'dr': None},
                                            ]
UserB   Photo         2         2014-03-02  [
                                            {'u': 4, 'r': False, 'dr': None},
                                            {'u': 5, 'r': True, 'dr': '2013-03-02'},
                                            {'u': 6, 'r': False, 'dr': None},
                                            {'u': 8, 'r': False, 'dr': None},
                                            ]
```

`u` is the recipient id, `r` is the read flag, and `dr` is the date of read. This way you can still do some lookup (e.g: Show notifications for UserB), without having to do many I/O, but you will have to create helper classes to post-process your notifications which presumably won't take much in terms of LOC and CPU resources.

But before you do this, think again about your 'inefficiency' concern, is it about reading?. If yes, with proper indexing reading shouldn't be a problem, databases like MySQL and Postgres can handle millions (even tens of millions) of rows just fine if you have proper indexing and query. If the concern is about writing, you can put it as a background task and have the user continue their activity without being blocked by the process. The solution above may give you lesser I/O but it sacrifices the simplicity especially when you want to revisit or extend the feature in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use use a `has_many through` association. It would fit perfectly on this situation. Also, you can make the model Notification `belongs_to :event` and the event type should be stored at the Event model. You can check more about that at: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Events are not stored in the same model. I want separate models for things like `Like`, `Post`, `Comment`, etc. Also, I know I can do has_many, but the question is should I really store that many duplicates (either by using a has_many through notification_read, or just storing it all in notifications). Because if a user does a simple event and he has 1000 followers, I would have 1000 new records for every small event. And events will happen often.

Answer (score 0):

A large scale site like what you're talking about usually use an asynchronous messaging broker and protocol such as ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ, etc., using a protocol such as JMS, STOMP, AMQP, MQTT, the list just goes on and on.

Anyway, how I'd probably implement such a thing would be that each user session has a sort of message listener subscribed to their corresponding user notification queue. Depending on the protocol in question would determine how one would exactly do this, but the simplest way would be for every user to get their own queue. Message brokers tend to handle message persistence via a combination of the file system and journal files which are much faster than relational databases for these purposes (think about it; this data isn't relational).

Being that this is Ruby and you didn't say that you're using JRuby, your choice of messaging would probably fall under STOMP or MQTT as the others tend to be more heavyweight.